# Extracting data from lines of log file in python

Tags: python, logfile

I need to extract time(02/Jan/2015:08:12), article_id, and user_id

line format looks like this:

```
67.15.143.7 - - [02/Jan/2015:08:12] "GET/click?article_id=25&user_id=104 HTTP/1.1" 200 2327
67.15.143.7 - - [02/Jan/2015:08:12] "GET/click?article_id=211&user_id=9408 HTTP/1.1" 200 380
```

I'm a beginner and I did search on google and stack overflow, but I haven't find the way to solve it. Can anyone help me? Thanks!

Comment: You probably want to start reading into python regular expression usage, the re module will probably get all the info out of the line you're after. Learning how to write a regex can be a steep learning curve but will pay off massively in the long run. Log analyser programs like logstash use regex heavily to extract info

Answer (score 1):

A simple regex can extract that.

```
>>> import re
>>> s = '''67.15.143.7 - - [02/Jan/2015:08:12] "GET/click?article_id=25&user_id=104 HTTP/1.1" 200 2327
... 67.15.143.7 - - [02/Jan/2015:08:12] "GET/click?article_id=211&user_id=9408 HTTP/1.1" 200 380'''
>>> re.findall('\[(.*?)\].*?article_id=(\d+).*?user_id=(\d+)',s)
[('02/Jan/2015:08:12', '25', '104'), ('02/Jan/2015:08:12', '211', '9408')]
```

Use `re.search` instead of `re.findall` if you want to apply the pattern to individual lines.

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
result = re.findall(r'.*\[(.+)\].+article\_id\=(\d+)\&user_id\=(\d+).*',your_string)
```